# Agregar valores aleatorios a filas de for

Tags: c#, bucle-for, validación

Nose muy bien como hacerlo pero busco poner valores aleatorios en una fila en la segunda, tengo un rango, y en la tercera volver a poner valores aleatorios. no se muy bien como hacerlo. Se hacer para hacerlo en general pero como hago para especificar que sea la fila 1 y 3 aleatorias y la fila 2 con numeros entre 1 y 5.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[,] numeros = new int[4,30];
for(int x=0;x<numeros.GetLength(0);x++)
            {
                for(int y=0;y<numeros.GetLength(1);y++)
                {
                    numeros[x,y] = rnd.Next(1,1001);
                    Console.Write(numeros[x,y]+"-");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0 Tienes prácticamente todos los datos que necesitas para preguntar si estás en la fila 1-2-3 (pregunta por X == 0,1,2). Intenta luego de haber leído la documentación. Por cierto, aquí otra lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y bienvenido a SOes, recuerda hacer el recorrido en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour (ganarás tu primera medalla)

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes de condicionar si la fila es igual a 1 o 3 si la condición es verdadera, puedes ingresar los números aleatorios y si es falso entonces ingresas los números del 1 al 5, Yo lo hice con un operador ternario, si no sabes como usarlos, [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) lo puedes ver.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
    int[,] numeros = new int[4,30];
    for(int x=0;x<numeros.GetLength(0);x++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<numeros.GetLength(1);y++)
            {
                numeros[x,y] = (x == 1 || x == 3) ? rnd.Next(1,1001): rnd.Next(1,5);
                Console.Write(numeros[x,y]+"-");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Agrega algún link donde el OP pueda consultar para conocer más acerca de los operadores ternarios, de favor 3: